# Associated primes to principal ideals in a Noetherian domain

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, localization, noetherian, integral-domain

Let $R$ be a Noetherian domain. Let $\mathcal S:=\{P \in\mathrm{Spec}(R) : P \in \mathrm{Ass}(R/xR)$, for some $ 0\ne x \in R\}$. Then how to show that $\cap_{P\in \mathcal S} R_P \subseteq R$ ?

Comment: Pick $a/b$ from the intersection. Let $P$ be an associated prime of $R/(bR:a)$. Then $P$ is associated to $R/bR$, a contradiction.